# Strtotime/86400 doesn't work (php)

Tags: php, datetime-format, strtotime

I tried to create a php script that take a date from a daterangepicker, creates two variables that are then converted in strtotime.

I then divide the difference by 86400 to return the number of days, but instead of returning one (when I pick one day), it returns 31. Do you have any idea of where I made a mistake?

Example when `$_POST['periode']=03/06/2018 00:00 - 04/06/2018 00:00`

```
        $datete=$_POST['periode'];
        list($debut, $fin) = explode(" - ", "$datete", 2);
        $debutTS=strtotime($debut);
        $finTS=strtotime($fin);
        $diff=($finTS-$debutTS)/86400
```

`$debutTS` returns  1520294400 and `$finTS` returns 1522972800. 
`$debutTS` should return 1527976800 
`$finTs` should return 1528063200

Any idea?

Comment: Because  `03/06/2018` is treated like `m/d/Y` by __default__, and you expect it to be `d/m/Y`.

Comment: Sure that’s not using US format? Try reversing the day/month, or using `-` as the separator instead of `/`

Comment: Use PHP's [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) and [DateTime::diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: @u_mulder thanks for the answer, but how can I treat it like d/m/y instead of d/m/y?

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)-class for this. It can also calculate the difference for you so there's no reason for doing that manually.

```
$dates = explode(' - ' , $_POST['periode']);

// Create the first date from your date/time format
$from = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dates[0]);

// Create the second date from your date/time format
$to = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $dates[1]);

// Get the difference
$interval = $from->diff($to);

// Get the difference in days (it's the %a token)
// No need to calculate anything manually
$diff = $interval->format('%a');

echo $diff;
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/HVukA